# 404 on update file with fileID on google drive api

Tags: lua, google-drive-api, http-status-code-404

I have seen this question asked a few times, but none of the answers were helpful. Unless it is a 'user permission' problem in which case I don't know how to handle it.

**Context**

- Created a new file (from a Lua app, so using REST)

  - used ?uploadType=resumable
  - from the return, captured responseHeaders['X-GUploader-UploadID'] and response['id'], same result for both
- File exists, can see it on Google Drive

Then, try to update, and I get 404 Not Found. Here is the Lua code:

**Code**

```
local url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files"
```

[userStateID has the id captured above]

```
url = url.."/".._G.lobal.userStateID.."/?uploadType=media"
url = url.."/?uploadType=media&upload_id=".._G.lobal.userStateID
```

[I tried both variations above, same result]

```
resbody = stuff

local headers = {['Content-type'] = "application/json",
  Authorization=oauth,
  ['user-agent'] = "SilkRoad ".._G.VERSION,
  ['X-Upload-Content-Type']="application/text; charset=utf-8",
  ['Content-Length']=string.len(resbody)
}
local params = {headers=headers,body=resbody}
network.request(url, "PUT", uploadListener, params )
```

[async network call in lua]

**Result**

{"responseHeaders":{"Content-Type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","X-GUploader-UploadID":"ABg5-UxILyJZKOABmdvQ2tDrsXrRTHY-pljfWSk67vcKyzcSoR28BoMjHG5gFi0a3GLUPVSU3T5bBvqlnK5qG0-lNEOc0Tp4vQ","Vary":"Origin, X-Origin","Date":"Sun, 30 May 2021 20:52:17 GMT","Alt-Svc":"h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"","Content-Length":"9","Server":"UploadServer"},"responseType":"text","phase":"ended","bytesEstimated":9,"response":"Not Found","name":"networkRequest","bytesTransferred":9,"status":404,"url":"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/?uploadType=media&upload_id=ABg5-UxG8zBq7ARLKAd7cE0FB2z9NG1Sv8gKlnH_QjDqluSOaun5oRRI3h7fXHHn1KqEW1DolBkMmh4GlgwgOGl9NOc","isError":false,"requestId":"<type 'userdata' is not supported by JSON.>"}

There is no 'user' to give privileges. But perhaps to use this mechanism, to update any file my app creates I have to then ask the user to go to their Drive and change permissions? That doesn't sound right. Maybe a flag I need to put on the metadata?

The 'X-GUploader-UploadID' is not documented, but same result if I use response['id']. I have verified that the id in Google Drive (for sharing) is the same id returned in response['id']. But says Not found when I use it for update.

BTW, just trying to update by reusing the resume URL or this variation:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?upload_id=...
```

has an odd result: no error, but the file is not updated.

Using PATCH instead of PUT on the original update has also a curious effect -- no error, but updates the file to empty. So perhaps that is the secret but I have to figure out how to pass the body correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had to:

- use resumable for the update (do it in 2 parts)
- add the fileID in the URL (as documented)
- use PATCH for the metadata update
- use PUT for the content update

Certainly could use better documentation or examples, at least for the REST API.